# Is it possible to programmatically transmit an audio file from a phone call in android?

Tags: android

I'm working on a protocol to transmit data from voice calls in android. Audio files will be played on a voice call without any role for the user. Is this possible programmatically?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more details. Is it possible for an ordinary app to do this on any Android device? No. Is it possible to do this on your own custom Android ROM on some specific device? It might be. But there's probably not going to be a ton of information available to you (try the xda-developers forums maybe), so you might have to do a lot of research yourself.

Comment: Planned to build an app for end users. What are the reasons for such a restriction?

Comment: Letting apps inject audio into the voice call uplink would be a security concern since it could be used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Never mind, found a workaround using DTMF (dual tone multi frequency) in call intent.